# $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="framework/resources/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var blink = function() {
            $('#blink').toggle();
       };
</script>
```

Throws an error saying

> $ is not a function

When using an external JavaScript file which gets referred after jQuery I can only seem to use jQuery within the `ready` function. Is there something I should know about using jQuery in this manner?

Comment: Where and how you are you loading jQuery?

Comment: Can you provide a link? It seems jQuery is not loaded correctly.

Answer (score 6):

That error means jquery isn't loaded

Answer (score 1):

jQuery may be conflicting with another definition, the fact that you can use it in the ready function seems to indicate that it is at least loaded.  Have you tried using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="framework/resources/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var blink = function() {
            jQuery('#blink').toggle();
       };
</script>
```

Sometimes it is cleaner to go direct to the object.  If you find that resolves your problem you may wish to switch to noConflict mode which is described in more detail in the docs here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 w00t seems to have forgotten this question, but this answer helped me with an identical problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referenced jQuery as the first script in your page? Does the path exist? Try using Google's, just to test:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: @Random downvoter: care to comment on why you don't think this 3-month old answer is *not helpful* for the OP? **The problem in the question is that jQuery isn't being loaded correctly**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jQuery is conflicting with any existing javascript library.

I hope this [link](http://www.adrogen.com/blog/jquery-conflict-is-not-a-function/) might help.