# jQuery Error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am having this issue due to using some third party script that is throwing me an error. The script relates to a wordpress plugin that has actually been published by the author.

I am using the 'iLightBox' plugin to display liteboxes for my images. However i need to set which images appear in the lightbox gallery. I have been using the developer website and found the following URL: http://www.ilightbox.net/faq.html

Script 5 appears to do what i need:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    (function(){
      var groupsArr = [];
      $('[rel^="ilightbox["]').each(function () {
        var group = this.getAttribute("rel");
        $.inArray(group, groupsArr) === -1 && groupsArr.push(group);
      });
      $.each(groupsArr, function (i, groupName) {
        $('[rel="' + groupName + '"]').iLightBox({ /* options */ });
      });
    })();

  });
```

I am running this code in a custom.js file and i can see using 'inspect element' in Chrome that the file is loading correctly but the script is erroring with the following:

"Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function".

I have read through some posts by other users who explain i need to encapsulate with a function and finish with '(jQuery)' however if i do this it just generates more errors.

Can anyone assist me?

My website where the error is showing: http://www.complete-models.com/uncategorized/16-alien-figure/

Comment: See the [documentation on how to use jQuery in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: It might be that the jquery library isn't being linked to your website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$ is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200053/is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your code just replace `$` to `jQuery`

```
$('[rel^="ilightbox["]').each(function () {
```

to

```
jQuery('[rel^="ilightbox["]').each(function () {
```

Comment: The code can be corrected with a simple `$` in the function definition. Just point to the documentation and close the question.

Comment: But this is also a solution. `jQuery` should work for OP.

Comment: I have replaced each '$' with 'jQuery' (as they also show up as errors).

My code looks like the below:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 
    (function(){
      var groupsArr = [];
      jQuery('[rel^="ilightbox["]').each(function () {
        var group = this.getAttribute("rel");
        jQuery.inArray(group, groupsArr) === -1 && groupsArr.push(group);
      });
      jQuery.each(groupsArr, function (i, groupName) {
        jQuery('[rel="' + groupName + '"]').iLightBox({ /* options */ });
      });
    })();

However i now get the error: "iLightBox is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you `custom.js` loaded after `jQuery` so in html file `<scipt>` tag for jQuery should be above `custom.js`

Comment: Is this what your talking about ?

'<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.complete-models.com/wp-content/themes/Avada%20-%20Child%20Theme/assets/js/custom.js?ver=93353d5d4faf72b60370326ed5860017'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.complete-models.com/wp-content/plugins/masterslider/public/assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js?ver=93353d5d4faf72b60370326ed5860017'>'

Comment: Yes, first jQuery need to be loaded so it's include script should written above custom.js